# Why is cricket not played at the Olympics?

Tags: cricket, olympics

I am a big fan of cricket but cricket is not played in Olympics I want to know the reason of cricket is not played in Olympics

Comment: Somewhat related Wikipedia article: [Cricket at the Summer Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_at_the_Summer_Olympics).

Comment: A similar question on Quora: [Why is cricket not part of the Olympic games?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-cricket-not-part-of-the-Olympic-games?share=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This what I found from the Internet readings,

Cricket was only held at the 1900 Summer Olympics in Paris, only two countries where participated in it, Britain and France where Britain won the Gold.

A cricket tournament was scheduled for 1904 Summer Olympics held in St. Louis but was eventually canceled.

Cricket's governing bodies have for much of their recent history been unwilling to return to the Olympics. In particular, the Board of Control for Cricket in India (BCCI) and England Cricket Board (ECB), considered international cricket's two most powerful boards, have long been opposed.

Also, Three leading cricket sides - England, Ireland and the West Indies - do not correspond to Olympic national teams, a problem also faced in rugby and association football. The United Kingdom competes at the Olympics as Great Britain with athletes from England, Scotland, Wales and those British Overseas Territories without their own Olympic team. Athletes from Northern Ireland can choose to represent either Great Britain or Ireland. In cricket, Scotland has its own team, Welsh players play for the England team, and the Ireland team represents the Republic and Northern Ireland together. In rugby, Team GB have to nominate one Home Nations team whose results will be used to determine whether Great Britain as a whole qualifies for the Olympics, but players from all the Home Nations can play for the combined team according to the usual Olympic rules.

But cricket may yet be reintroduced. The International Cricket Council is pitching for 20-over cricket in the next Olympics. As ICC said that He said that he did not think there would be any opposition from ICC members England or West Indies due to the fact that they would not be able to compete at a Games under those banners.

For more details: https://www.bbc.com/sport/cricket/39445193
                  https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2017/jul/25/cricket-on-verge-making-application-olympic-inclusion

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE, please do include if there are any other sources.

Comment: just added one more

Answer (score 4):

Cricket, although extremely popular in Asian countries is not very popular in Europe or North America (a case can be made for England, but it is seen as a rich man's game, so still not very popular). They make many of the decisions surrounding the Olympics, as you can see the majority of the members of the IOC (international olympics committee) are members of Europe or North America. (source: https://www.olympic.org/ioc-members-list)

Also, the International Cricket Council is notoriously bad at trying to make the sport more popular, they recently shot down a proposed remediation to the current format of the World Cup that, according to mass belief, would encourage the growth of cricket in new countries.

TLDR: Cricket isn't popular in the majority of the world and the governing council isn't doing anything to change that

Answer (score 3):

Cricket was to be played in the 1896 Olympics, but never took place due to a lack of participants.

In 1900, four teams played (Holland, Belgium, France, and England), but two (France and England) played only one match. The participating teams did not realize that they were competing in the Olympics. However, in 1912, cricket was recognized as played during the 1900 Olympics by the International Olympic Committee. Therefore, England received a gold medal and France received a silver medal after recognition.

Cricket was to be played at the 1904 Olympics, but never took place due to a lack of facilities.

According to my sources, the reasons cricket was not included after the 1904 Olympics include lack of consistent participation and lack of attention toward it.

Sources: ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_at_the_1900_Summer_Olympics#Aftermath)) ([2](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/134962.html))

Comment: hmmm.. interesting.. i recall reading somewhere that cricket is a gentleman's sport and therefore the icc refused for cricket to be a part of the olympics, so as not to mix it with other sports.

Answer (score 3):

Cricket was penciled in as an event in the very first modern Olympic Games at Athens in 1896, it was listed in the original program but was later shelved due to an insufficient number of entries. Four years later in the 1900 Paris Olympics, only four teams entered the fray — Great Britain, Belgium, Holland, and the hosts, France. Belgium and Holland withdrew from the cricket competition after their co-hosting bids were turned down. Therefore, the final match was contested between the teams of the two nations across the English Channel, Great Britain and France. Great Britain won the 12-a-side match contested over two days, cricket has never featured in the Olympic Games since.

The game of cricket has 105 full members from across the world. However, only 10 of these members are full members with “Test status”. There are many reasons as to why cricket took so long to mobilize popular opinion. For one, the English Cricket Board had an issue with the Summer Olympics clashing with its traditional cricketing calendar. Development of local infrastructure at a new country with no history of the game is going to be a hard sell, no bums on seats for an alien sport is not appealing to broadcasters either.

As of now, the traditional cricketing nations have nothing to gain in terms of an Olympic medal as the game’s biggest and prestigious contests are to be had in Test matches and the ODI World Cups. The Olympics should hence be pegged as a high-visibility showcase with a commitment for initiation into cricket.

Details : http://www.thehindu.com/thread/sports/no-spot-the-olympics-its-not-cricket/article17949431.ece